# How to reorder a graph with multiple variable based on one value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder the following graph based on the rank of the lowest confidence interval (`conf.low`). This means that Austria (AU) should be the first country, Bulgaria (BG) the second and Belgium (BE) the third. I know there is a way to do it manually by choosing the order of the country variable but i prefer to find a way to do it automatically since i have 30 countries. Could someone help?

[image]

Here is the data and the code:

```
df= structure(list(cntry = structure(1:3, .Label = c("AU", "BE", 
"BG"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(0.0053, 0.01740, 
0.0036), conf.low = c(-0.0257, 0.0005, 
-0.0006), conf.high = c(0.0365, 0.0343, 
0.0079)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  arrange(estimate) %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(estimate, 3),cntry==1, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, cntry,label=label)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(vjust= -1)  + 
  geom_linerange(mapping=aes(xmin=conf.low , xmax=conf.high, y=cntry)) + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=cntry))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `forcats::fct_reorder()` you could do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  arrange(estimate) %>%
  mutate(label = replace(round(estimate, 3), cntry==1, '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(estimate, fct_reorder(cntry, conf.low, .desc = TRUE),label=label)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(vjust= -1)  + 
  geom_linerange(mapping=aes(xmin=conf.low , xmax=conf.high, y=cntry)) + 
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=estimate, y=cntry))+
  ylab("Country")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
df= structure(list(cntry = structure(1:3, .Label = c("AU", "BE", 
                                                     "BG"), class = "factor"), estimate = c(0.0053, 0.01740, 
                                                                                            0.0036), conf.low = c(-0.0257, 0.0005, 
                                                                                                                  -0.0006), conf.high = c(0.0365, 0.0343, 
                                                                                                                                          0.0079)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```